# Calculate prior 6 months. Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Sample Data

[image: 1]

In my data, I have to calculate the current 6 months of usage and prior 6 months of usage. I already have calculations for the current 6 months. Now I need to do the calculations for 6 months Prior to the current 6 months. Can someone have any advice?

```
Current 6 Months = 
CALCULATE (
   [Full Price (modified)],
   DATESINPERIOD (
      'Dates_Jul20-Jun22'[Date],
      MAX ( 'Dates_Jul20-Jun22'[Date] ),
      -6,
      MONTH
    )
)
```

Same with the 3 months prior to the current 3 months.

```
Current 3 Months = 
CALCULATE (
   [Full Price (modified)],
   DATESINPERIOD (
      'Dates_Jul20-Jun22'[Date],
      MAX ( 'Dates_Jul20-Jun22'[Date] ),
      -3,
      MONTH
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data? and also the code for measure - [Full Price (modified)]

Comment: Hi, @mkRabbani I added a sample data screenshot in the post. Here is the emasure for Full Price (modified) = IF(ISBLANK(SUM('db'[FullPrice])), 0, SUM('db'[FullPrice]))

Comment: @Gene Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

```
Prior n Months =
VAR _priormonths = 12
VAR _currentmonths = 6
VAR _current =
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Table'[Date], MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), - _currentmonths, MONTH )
VAR _prior =
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Table'[Date], MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), - _priormonths, MONTH )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Full Price] ), _prior )
        - CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Full Price] ), _current )
```